# How to scroll top to botton using Android driver

Tags: appium

I tried scrollTo() to scroll my app page using andriod driver, but not worked because it is deprecated from javaclient 4.1.2.

I have gone through below link but couldn't find any solution .
[How can I scroll an android app page from top to bottom using appium driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30867765/how-can-i-scroll-an-android-app-page-from-top-to-bottom-using-appium-driver)

Please provide me solution

Answer (score 2):

My example is from python but it will work for Java as well just use java syntax to find element like

```
driver.find_element_by_android_uiautomator('new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().textContains("**/Put some text which is at bottom of screen to scroll screen/**").instance(0))')
```

for more details you can go-through the https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/uiautomator/UiScrollable.html and https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/uiautomator-testing.html

Answer (score 0):

User swipe method as below:

```
driver.swipe(startx, starty, endx, endy, duration);
```

e.g. for swipe down

```
driver.swipe(100, 100, 100, 900, 3000);
```

According you can change the x and y co-ordinates.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this below code, i was trying this code on settings page..

```
AppiumDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap1);
driver.scrollTo("About phone");
```

Pass the String which is present in the bottom of your app page.

```
driver.scrollTo("Enter your value");
```

Use appropriate wait Statements.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Test
    public void testScroll()throws Exception
    {
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            if (driver.findElement(By.name("end_item")).isDisplayed())
            {
                driver.findElement(By.name("end_item")).click();
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                verticalScroll();
            }

        }
    }
    public void verticalScroll()
    {
        size=driver.manage().window().getSize();
        int y_start=(int)(size.height*0.60);
        int y_end=(int)(size.height*0.30);
        int x=size.width/2;
        driver.swipe(x,y_start,x,y_end,4000);
    }
```

The above example works with vertical scroll and it is based on the example given at this blog for horizontal scroll http://qaautomated.blogspot.in/2016/02/how-to-do-horizontal-scroll-in-appium.html I hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the following the code snippet to scroll down but please make sure you catch the exceptions.

```
        try {
            driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()).scrollIntoView(text(\"\"))");
        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("whatever");
        }
```